# Host Checker issue with Juniper Network Connect (VPN) on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn, juniper

A company I am working for uses Juniper to provide a VPN access from outside (or from inside with a "foreign" computer).

When I try to connect to the VPN from inside but with a "foreign" computer, I get the error: "You're not allowed to open a session. Contact your administrator"
I tried with several browsers and Chrome is more verbose ^^. It says:
" your computer security is not satisfactory.
Host checker is not supported. Please contact your administrator"
And then I can clic a "retry" button.
When I do so, after a while I have some more messages:

"your system is not compatible with Host Checker"

- you must activate Active-X components to get a compatibility with Host Checker [...]
- OR you must install a JVM [...]"

[Juniper VPN error on retry image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBldW.jpg)

Well, getting this message on Chrome seems a bit strange as I understand only IE uses Active-X but OK, on Active-X controls are activated. 
And I also updated my Java plugins to have them up-to-date and it still doesn't work.

I also tried several things with no effect:
- I have tried to turn the firewall off prior to connect to the VPN
- change the way my computer connects to the internet (proxy, no proxy etc.) but there is no change. - and obviously I do have access to the internet.

I am also able to get to another company's network through another VPN (cisco) with the same computer and from the same location. 
- I tried to connect to Juniper VPN while running the other VPN /or not and still no change...

Does anyone have any idea please?

Thanks for your help !

Stéphanie

Comment: I found how to make it work! I use "Private" sessions in IE and in Firefox and it works. Hope this can help other people.

Comment: If you are getting this message "" your computer security is not satisfactory. "
Please update System Antivirus and remove user account from "Remote Desktop Users" group from your local account.
Re-join user account on "Remote Desktop Users" and check it.